is it possible to use traefik.me & cert manager for local development with kubernetes?
So basically im trying to use https for my local development and i was thinking of using traefik.me which routes all subdomains to localhost; and so i want to use their certificate for my local apps within my kubernetes cluster.
but the issuer is i don't know how to do it and i am new to both kubernetes and cert manager; can someone please guide me to solve this.
this is what i have so far
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-web-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
  cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - traefik.me
    - api.traefik.me
    - beta.traefik.me
    - myapp.traefik.me
    secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
    - host: myapp.traefik.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: beta.traefik.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: api.traefik.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: keda-add-ons-http-interceptor-proxy
                port:
                  number: 8080

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-tls
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  secretName: myapp-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: Issuer
  dnsNames:
    - traefik.me
    - api.traefik.me
    - beta.traefik.me
    - myapp.traefik.me
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    size: 2048

but the logs of the cert manager deployment are:
E1211 19:23:40.601353       1 sync.go:208] "propagation check failed" err="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" logger="cert-manager.controller" resource_na
me="myapp-tls-1-3528601542-974909028" resource_namespace="myapp" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="traefik.me" type="HTTP-01"
I1211 19:23:50.313309       1 pod.go:59] "found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" logger="cert-manager.controller.http01.selfCheck.http01.ensurePod" resource_name
="myapp-tls-1-3528601542-3776680831" resource_namespace="myapp" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="api.traefik.me" type="HTTP-01" related_re
source_name="cm-acme-http-solver-jzh75" related_resource_namespace="myapp" related_resource_kind="" related_resource_version=""
I1211 19:23:50.313399       1 service.go:45] "found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" logger="cert-manager.controller.http01.selfCheck.
http01.ensureService" resource_name="myapp-tls-1-3528601542-3776680831" resource_namespace="myapp" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="api.tr
aefik.me" type="HTTP-01" related_resource_name="cm-acme-http-solver-h49bd" related_resource_namespace="myapp" related_resource_kind="" related_resource_version="
"



Your current setup uses HTTP-01 challenge which is not supported on your configuration with traefik.me. It is trying to verify your domain ownership on the public internet via the ACME provider (Let’s Encrypt). However this is not feasible in your use case, as you are using it for your local deployment.
Alternative for you to still use traefik.me, you can switch to self-signed certificate for your use case.
Add issuer and point it to your certificate:

Create an Issuer with type selfSigned:

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: issuer-selfsigned
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selfSigned: {}


Map your issuer to your Certificate:

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-tls
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  secretName: myapp-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: issuer-selfsigned   #update this line with your new issuer
    kind: Issuer
  dnsNames:
    - api.traefik.me
    - beta.traefik.me
    - myapp.traefik.me
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    size: 2048


The problem with self signged is that it won't enable Oauth, what i ended up doing is getting the private key and certificate chain from traefik.me and creating the certificate secrete manually with kubectl in order for Oauth to work, thanks for the reply
